# Should I check for an internet connection when I open an MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, reachability

In my iOS app I want to show an MKMapView. Should I check for reachability before I open the map view?

In most cases the user will have the map he wants cached so he could open the map view without internet connectivity. So why not allow him to open the map view?

Will my app be approved for the App Store if I don't check for reachability? Or will it get rejected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to check reachability, but you should check for when the map view fails to load using the `MKMapViewDelegate` method [`mapViewDidFailLoadingMap:withError:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapViewDidFailLoadingMap%3awithError%3a). Rejections sometimes happen when you fail to respond to these errors.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't get discarded for that, I've made a map app that doesn't check for an internet connection and I'm sure plenty of others have too.